# Software corrupted during upgrade to 19.04

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, upgrade, icons, data-corruption

I had followed [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-ubuntu-19-04-directly-from-command-line) to upgrade my system from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 19.04..

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After issuing this command, as the update progress reached almost 75%, the system automatically went to sleep. Thereafter, I was unable to login back again. I think that this happened because the system automatically timed out at the same time when the code related to the login session was altered during the update. And at last, I rebooted the system. 
But when it rebooted, as the update hadn't finished, the OS is now unable to display icons system wide. I recall that it had printed `setting up googlechrome-stable` in the terminal while updating.. The logout happened after that. So now, when I click on the space for the Google Chrome icon in the taskbar, it successfully loads up Google Chrome. Surely, the OS is unusable at this stage and I really wanna reinstall everything. But, is there a way to backup all my data..? Neither the terminal nor the Files app is working. I've tried opening the terminal using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T. But, it doesn't open up. The icons on the taskbar aren't working either..

Please tell me a way to copy all my data.. I'm running Windows 10 - Ubuntu dual boot.. It's okay if it's possible to access the Ubuntu partition from Windows too..

Comment: Can you open a console TTY? Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 and see if you can login. From there you should be able to backup your data to a mounted external drive.

Comment: The guide you used has errors and is dangerous. I would avoid that website from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access Ubuntu from Windows. Boot from the installation DVD/USB drive (live).
Select Try "Ubuntu"  and copy/paste anything you want.